# Dynamically Create Link Javascript

Tags: javascript, href, createelement

I'm trying to set my text as a link so that when I click on it, it runs a function. Right now I just have it set to google.com to try to get the text to appear as a link, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. It's just static text. Any suggestions?

```
        var leftDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create left div
        leftDiv.id = "left"; //Assign div id
        leftDiv.setAttribute("style", "float:left; width:66.5%; line-height: 26px; text-align:left; font-size:12pt; padding-left:8px; height:26px;"); //Set div attributes
        leftDiv.style.background =  divColor;
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', 'google.com');
        user_name = a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fullName + ' '));

        leftDiv.appendChild(user_name); // Add name to left div
```

Comment: A link to another site, I think, has to use a full URI/domain name: `google.com` needs to be `http://google.com` for the `href` to link to Google.

Comment: It still shows up as static text instead of a link.

Comment: You are never inserting the link into the document, only the text node. `a.appendChild` returns the node just appended.

Answer (score 27):

Look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajXEW/

I added some comments inside the code that explain the diffrent steps.

```
    var leftDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create left div
    leftDiv.id = "left"; //Assign div id
    leftDiv.setAttribute("style", "float:left; width:66.5%; line-height: 26px; text-align:left; font-size:12pt; padding-left:8px; height:26px;"); //Set div attributes
    leftDiv.style.background =  "#FF0000";
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href =  'google.com'; // Insted of calling setAttribute 
    a.innerHTML = "Link" // <a>INNER_TEXT</a>
    leftDiv.appendChild(a); // Append the link to the div
    document.body.appendChild(leftDiv); // And append the div to the document body
```

Comment: Why is `a = document.createElement('a');` not `var a = document.createElement('a');` ?

Comment: var a and a is same  var is optional in javascript

Comment: Without `var`, this code creates a variable on the global scope. So this code creates a `window.a` variable that anyone else can overwrite and modify at any time during the running of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/HknMF/5/

```
var divColor = "red";
var fullName = "bob";

var leftDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create left div
        leftDiv.id = "left"; //Assign div id
        leftDiv.setAttribute("style", "float:left; width:66.5%; line-height: 26px; text-align:left; font-size:12pt; padding-left:8px; height:26px;"); //Set div attributes
        leftDiv.style.background =  divColor;
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', 'google.com');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fullName + ' '));

        leftDiv.appendChild(a); // Add name to left div

    document.body.appendChild(leftDiv);
```